# how to find the column number in a text file using unix commands

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, grep

Suppose I have a text file with 6 columns as below

```
a|b|c|d|e|f
```

I know that somwhere in the file the character 'd' exist, but I want to know the column no for it

I have used the following command

```
awk 's=index($0,"d"){print "position="s}' filename
```

but it counts the delimiters too which I dont want....I want the output to be 4 in case of "d"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

define "|" as Record Seperator, and use NR variable in awk:

```
awk -v RS="|" '/^d$/{print NR;}' filename
```

change `^d$` to whatever you want to match.

Comment: This will fail if you have more than one line, and you need to remove a `{` to `awk -v RS="|" '/^d$/{print NR}'`

Answer (score 6):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -v val='d' -F '|' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==val) {print i} }' file
4
```

Comment: Works, but give this error: `awk: warning: escape sequence `\|' treated as plain `|'`. This is ok `-F'|'` (no escape) or this `-F\|` (my choice). Removing the `exit` and it will work on multiple  lines.

Comment: Strangely my awk on OSX wasn't complaining about `\|`.

Comment: It does complain on my `Ubuntu` 12.04

Comment: warnings are a fickle thing. It's not unusual for some awks to issue warnings about things that other awks choose not to. There's also a `--lint` flag for gawk that will produce even more warnings. POSIX leaves it up to awk implementers to issue warnings as they see fit and if/when it's convenient in their specific implementation.